# Sample size required for normal approximation - null hypothesis or estimate?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, normality-assumption

Consider a simple hypothesis test with a binomial distribution $Bin(p,n)$:

$$
H_0: p = p_0, \\
H_a: p \neq p_0
$$

and my estimate for $p$ is $\hat{p}$.

If I wanna do a normal approximation, a common standard is to check if $np(1-p) \geq 10$. Should I use $p_0$ or $\hat{p}$ in this formula? Should I check with both of them?

Comment: You should use the estimated p, since that is what you have available, while the true p could be made up to any arbitrary number until it fits your story.

Comment: @user2974951 While I agree with your comment, I'm not sure how I shall counter the argument "but we assume that p_0 is true during hypothesis testing, so we also should use p_0 while checking for normal approximation". I can't figure what is wrong with this argument.

Comment: If you do not have any data then all you have is a hypothesis, and you can check what to expect if this hypothesis holds. However, if you have some data, you should use that instead of assuming, why assume when you have data?

Comment: @user2974951 Because this Normal approximation evidently is intended to compute a p-value based on the *null* hypothesis, it's hard to see how any amount of data would be needed to justify it.